# Windows 10 start icon doesn't react on right-click

Tags: windows-10, icons, start-menu

So I just upgraded from windows 10 Home to Education, and things started going a tad bad.

Whenever I try to right-click the windows logo, all that happens is my cursor jumping about 5 pixels up and left.

---

Another detail that might be important is that some of the icons on the taskbar show up as the default icon, and not it's actual icon (currently only Visual Studio 2015 and WinRar act so strange, though reinstalling it could fix it, haven't tried yet).

Comment: I suggest you perform a Reset and choose to keep your personal files.  This means you will indeed have to install your application again but might solve the problems after you used an unsupported method to upgrade Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Education

Comment: I Entered a new activation key, by doing this I got a windows update to upgrade to Education. I doubt that's an unsupported method.

Comment: Unless your Windows 10 Home installation was a VLK there isn't any support way to move from Windows 10 to Windows 10 Education since its only license through a volume license

Comment: I used a key from the store for Home, then used DreamSpark for a key to upgrade to Education.

Comment: I literally have no idea how you accomplished that.  There is no direct upgrade path from Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Enterprise.  I am finding ways workarounds to change Windows 10 Professional tin Windows 10 Enterprise or Windows 10 Education but that only works because Windows 10 Professional can be licensed with a volume license

Comment: Miscommunication here, I thought you were referring to the Home version being a VLK. The Education I got through Dreamspark, meaning it's a VLK. But as I said, I just entered an Education key as activation key, and the windows upgrade popped up as an update.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?  How this even worked confuses me.  You have never been able to migrate from a Home or Professional edition of Windows to an Enterprise edition ( which is basically what Education is ) Is your edition actually being reported as Windows 10 Education?